# Make taskbar visible whilst fullscreen

Tags: taskbar

I want my taskbar to be visible whilst watching twitch, both by default and also I'd like to know how to toggle between visible and invisible, ideally just by using a keyboard shortcut. Are these possible?

Comment: Set the taskbar to hide and then use this to toggle:   https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-11-hide-taskbar-shortcuts/?newsletter_popup=1

Comment: Thanks but I don't think this will make the bar visible in fullscreen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this small freeware :
[Hide Taskbar](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/hide-taskbar-windows-7-hotkey).

This utility uses the key combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>
to hide or show the taskbar.

This app does not hide the taskbar automatically on running it, but
allows you to choose, using the hotkeys, when to hide and unhide.

---

If this app doesn't help in your case, you could use these Windows
shortcuts:

- **Win+T** : browse the apps on your Taskbar.
  You can move between them with the arrow keys and launch
  an app with Enter
- **Win+B** : highlights the System Tray.

For more information,see the article
[How to Navigate Your Windows 10 Taskbar With Keyboard Shortcuts](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/windows-10-taskbar-keyboard-shortcuts/).

Comment: Nice app but it doesn't make the taskbar visible in fullscreen.

Comment: Try the shortcuts of Win+T and/or Win+B.

Comment: These both work. Perfect; thanks. Would they have worked even without the addon I wonder?

Comment: Yes, but why didn't you accept my answer?

Comment: Oh maybe I made a mistake but I thought those shortcuts worked even without the app. Was I mistaken?

Comment: Of course they do - this was my comment.

Comment: No, Your comment was to try the shortcuts. It wasn't clear that they required the addon to work. Thanks for now clarifying. I've now accepted and upvoted your answer, after unaccepting mine.

Comment: I mean perhaps it should have been taken as read that the shortcuts required the addon, but never mind. At least it's sorted now. Bless.

Comment: Win+T and Win+B are good but Ctrl+Esc with the addon is not, as it results in the stream I'm wanting to watch being obscured by the windows menu that pops up as a result.

Answer (score 1):

Try the shortcuts of Win+T and/or Win+B. –
harrymc

This worked as per the comment from harrymc posted above. Not sure if it requires the addon he linked or not.